# Vagrant running DSTK refuses connections at port 8080

Tags: macos, curl, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm very new to the land of virtual machines and vagrant, so please forgive my general ignorance about all of this.

The other day, I downloaded [DSTK](http://datasciencetoolkit.org) vagrant box and followed the instructions on the documentation page to get it set up so I could run many, many thousands of requests through it on my local machine rather than bombarding the public server (and also, it should be faster; and also, DSTK is down at the moment so it was the only option).

After many hours of waiting for vagrant to `add` and `init` the box on my tired old hard drive, it worked! I used curl to make a few requests, got the expected responses, and patted myself on the back. I closed my terminal and put away my computer and drank beer.

... And then, the next morning, this happened:

```
$ curl -d "Joe Biden" "localhost:8080/text2people"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I can't work out why. I tried `vagrant suspend; vagrant up`. Same thing. `vagrant halt; vagrant up`. Same thing. When I've halted vagrant and run 'vagrant up' again, this appears in the readout, which makes me think it ought to be working.

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```

I can run `vagrant ssh` and get in, look around, and I see that all the files are in the right right place.

I suppose I could remove the box and re-add it, but it really did take hours to `add` and `init` and now I'm running up against a deadline where I need to it work, and I imagine there is a very simple thing of which I am not aware that is causing my problem. Google has thus far been unhelpful, probably because of how unfamiliar I am with vagrant, generally.

Comment: FWIW, since the website's down, here's a Google cache of the exact instructions I followed. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Cxhg9LLQoUEJ:www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us#setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's not a problem with vagrant or virtualbox at all.

It turns out I just didn't stop to think about whether `curl` could be the culprit, and when I got around to this again, fixing it was as simple as `curl "127.0.0.1:8080/..."`. Apparently curl (or at least the native Mac OSX implementation) doesn't like `localhost`.

I did try to Google about it for a few minutes, though, and I came across my own un-answered question, which was sort of a bummer—so in case anybody else ever has this problem, here's your fix.

```
curl "localhost:8080/text2people" -d "Joe Biden"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

curl "127.0.0.1:8080/text2people" -d "Joe Biden"
[
  {
    "title": "",
    "gender": "m",
    "start_index": 0,
    "first_name": "Joe",
    "end_index": 9,
    "surnames": "Biden",
    "ethnicity": {
      "percentage_american_indian_or_alaska_native": 0.0,
      "rank": 114852,
      "percentage_two_or_more": 0.0,
      "percentage_of_total": 5.0e-05,
      "percentage_hispanic": 0.0,
      "percentage_white": 96.45,
      "percentage_black": 0.0,
      "percentage_asian_or_pacific_islander": 0.0
    },
    "matched_string": "Joe Biden"
  }
]
```

Comment: Alternatively, adding the `--ipv4` switch to a curl request to localhost fixes it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the same problem, in my case the solution was to ensure that the following line is not commented on the Vagrantfile:

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"